# Angular Universal - angularx-social-login not working on Firefox

Tags: angular, firefox, angular-universal, angular10, angular-social-login

I used angularx-social-plugin right before enabling SSR and seemed to be fine.
Now that the app is universal, it breaks on firefox.

On any other browser, it works normal but in Firefox, I have these warnings in the console after page load

[image: Errors on page load. unreachable code after return statement]

They might be the reason why when I try to use one login provider, I have this error
[image: Error when trying to use signInWithPopup(new FacebookProvider). Login providers not ready yet. Are there errors on your console?]

All this, only on Firefox.

Is it because of the SSR?

Comment: I figured it was because of an extension called Facebook Container in Firefox. Basically, the extension blocks any script or cookie from Facebook and that made `angularx-social-plugin` fail to initialize the `FacebookProvider` which lead to whole module to crash.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. You need to disable the enhanced data protection in Firefox:
[image]